# How to Save Relation In MongoDB with GraphQL args

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I don't fully understand the way that MongoDB relations work, but I believe the relation albums to artist would be that the **artist** (I call them users) has a list of Album IDs in an array, probably called `albums: []`, and all albums have a `createdBy: {id: 12345}`.

So I want to create an updateAlbum call, but I don't know how to save the ID into `createdBy:` from GraphQL.

Here is the schema:

```
var AlbumSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    dateUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    fName: String,
    lName: String,
    albums: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Album'}]
});
```

Here is the GraphQL type:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        fName: {type: GraphQLString},
        lName: {type: GraphQLString},
        albums: {type: new GraphQLList(AlbumType)}
    })
})
const AlbumType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Album',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type:GraphQLID},
        name: {type:GraphQLString},
        dateCreated: {type: GraphQLString},
        dateUpdated: {type: GraphQLString},
        users: {type: new GraphQLList(UserType)},
        createdBy: {type: UserType}
    })
})
```

Here is the updateAlbum call:

```
updateAlbum: {
            type: AlbumType,
            args: {
                id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                name: {type: GraphQLString},
                createdById: {type: GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parentValue, args){
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    console.log(args.createdById)
                    const date = Date().toString()
                    ALBUM.findOneAndUpdate(
                        {"_id": args.id},
                        { "$set":{name: args.name,
                                dateUpdated: date,
                                createdBy: args.createdById}},
                        {"new": true} //returns new document
                    ).exec((err, res) => {
                        if(err) reject(err)
                        else resolve(res)
                    })
                })
            }
        }
```

How do I save the relation in the updateAlbum function?

Here is what I got - if I save `createdBy: THE_ID_STRING` it doesn't do it correctly and when I query I get a weird string of unknown characters "Zj�����\b�\u001e�(" which the ID string `console.log()` as "5a6ac1afac97c908dc1edf28"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Mongo Schema definitions, I'd say your understanding of references is correct, seeing as how you're using the document reference correctly by using `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Now all you have to do is map `GraphQLID` as the GraphQL *type* for `createdBy`.
I like to use an alias for this, as `MongoId` for 2 reasons.

*1)* So I know explicitly from only looking at the GraphQL Types definitions what behavior to expect without having to go back to the Mongo Schema if I forget what Data Type I assigned it as: `Schema.Types.ObjectId` || `String`.

*2)* And most importantly, to emphasize visually the important distinction between a standard `String` type from an `Object` type since Mongo uses `Object.prototype` for document index `_id`s even tho they look visually like they're coming from `String.prototype`.

Such as:

```
import {
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLID as MongoId,
  GraphQLString as StringType,
  GraphQLObjectType as ObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

const AlbumType = new ObjectType({
    name: 'Album',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: MongoId },
        name: { type: StringType },
        dateCreated: { type: StringType },
        dateUpdated:  {type: StringType },
        users: { type: new GraphQLList(UserType)},
        createdBy: { type: MongoId}
    })
})
```

BTW, you should verify your `id` shouldn't be `_id`.

If you need further clarification you can refer to a project I just finished involving this very issue.  GraphQL Types are [here](https://github.com/TobiahRex/nj2jp/blob/master/server/graphiql/db/graphql/types/contactTypes.js#L57).

Comment: @KevinDanikowski Awesome. Glad I could help!